# changing default theme to apple on jstree

Tags: jstree

I am trying to change the theme on jstree from default to apple as below:

```
"themes": {
        "theme": "apple",
        "dots": true,
        "icons": true,
        "url": "../../themes/apple/style.css"
    },
```

When I load the tree, I dont see any dots for folder images. Any ideas what I am doing wrong. style.css file above points to the apple folder css file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this did it for me:

```
$("#div_id").jstree("set_theme", "apple");
```